# Numpy installation?

Tags: 12.04, python

I used VIRTUALBOX to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my windows pc. I used apt-get to install Python 2.7 that shipped with 12.04. I followed the directives I saw on this site to install Numpy, Scipy, Matplot all failed. I download tar source file of these modules. How do I install them manually? Someone pls help, I'm getting frustrated.

Comment: All of those are available via the software center.  Is there a reason you do not want to get them from there?

Comment: Software center didn't work, John.

Answer (score 4):

Install them using the software center instead of trying to do it manually.

From the [SciPy install page](http://www.scipy.org/install.html) :

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose
```

> The versions in Ubuntu 12.10 and Debian 7.0 meet the current SciPy stack
>   specification. Users might also want to add the NeuroDebian repository
>   for extra SciPy packages.